# Camel: use datasource configured by spring-boot

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a project and in it I'm using `spring-boot-jdbc-starter` and it automatically configures a DataSource for me.
Now I added `camel-spring-boot` to project and I was able to successfully create routes from Beans of type `RouteBuilder`. 
But when I'm using sql component of camel it can not find datasource. Is there any simple way to add Spring configured datasource to `CamelContext`? In samples of camel project they use spring xml for datasource configuration but I'm looking for a way with java config. This is what I tried:

```java
@Configuration
public class SqlRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
  @Bean
  public SqlComponent sqlComponent(DataSource dataSource) {
    SqlComponent sqlComponent = new SqlComponent();
    sqlComponent.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return sqlComponent;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("sql:SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE STATUS NOT LIKE 'completed'")
            .to("mock:sql");
  }
}
```

Comment: My bad, there is no need to sqlComponent Bean. As all spring beans are accessible by CamelContext Just add `?dataSource=dataSource` at the end of sql endpoint and it works as expected

Comment: You should post that comment as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have to publish it because although the answer is in the commentary, you may not notice it, and in my case such a configuration was necessary to run the process.
The use of the SQL component should look like this:

```
         from("timer://dbQueryTimer?period=10s")
                .routeId("DATABASE_QUERY_TIMER_ROUTE")
                .to("sql:SELECT * FROM event_queue?dataSource=#dataSource")
                .process(xchg -> {
                    List<Map<String, Object>> row = xchg.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                    row.stream()
                            .map((x) -> {
                                EventQueue eventQueue = new EventQueue();
                                eventQueue.setId((Long)x.get("id"));
                                eventQueue.setData((String)x.get("data"));
                                return eventQueue;
                            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                })
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"******Database query executed - body:${body}******");
```

Note the use of `?dataSource=#dataSource`. The `dataSource` name points to the DataSource object configured by Spring, it can be changed to another one and thus use different DataSource in different routes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample/example code (Java DSL). For this I used

- Spring boot
- H2 embedded Database
- Camel

on startup spring-boot, creates table and loads data. Then camel route, runs "select" to pull the data.

**Here is the code**:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("timer://timer1?period=1000")
    .setBody(constant("select * from Employee"))
    .to("jdbc:dataSource")
    .split().simple("${body}")
    .log("process row ${body}")
```

[full example in github](https://github.com/RakeshBhat/rb-springinmemdb-example)